# The Integral Test enables us to bound the error approximation of the series

Tags: calculus

$$S = \sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{ n(\ln{n})^5}$$

One partial sum is given by

$$S_{40} = \sum\limits_{n=3}^{40} \frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^5}$$

What upper bound does it yield for the error $S-S_{40}$?

Do I solve both of the sums with the integral test and use $S-S_{40}$ to get the answer?

Comment: I determined the answer using:"solve both of the sums with the integral test and use S-S40 to get the answer". Should i remove the question or leave it up for others to see.

Comment: None of the above. Enter your solution an an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if we let $$S(s;k) = \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n \ln^s(n)}$$ then for $s>1$, we have
$$\dfrac{\ln^{1-s}(k+1)}{s-1} =\int_{k+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x \ln^s(x)} \leq S(s;k) \leq \int_k^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x \ln^s(x)} = \int_{\ln(k)}^{\infty} \dfrac{dt}{t^s} = \dfrac{\ln^{1-s}(k)}{s-1}$$
The error bound you want is for $S(5;40)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$ S-S_{40}=R_{40} \leq \int_{40}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln^5(x)}dx. $$